# argument must be coercible to non-negative integer in R

Tags: r, anova

I am trying to run the following command on my dataset;

```
   pbad2way(formula = Balance~Occupation+Gender+Occupation:Gender, data = 
plxsell, est= "mom", nboot= 5000)
```

name of dataset is plxsell
Balance, Occupation, Gender are the columns

but i am receiving following error;

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
In addition: Warning message:
In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : first element used of 'length.out' argument

Please help.

Thanks
Akhil

Comment: Hey Akhil, the community would be much more helpful if you could make your question [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

This error message appears **when a function expects a number but receives something else**.

For example the `seq_len` function expects a number:

```
seq_len(3) # no error, since function receives a number
seq_len(NA_character_) # Errors, since function expected a number and did not receive one
seq_len("a") # Errors, since function expected a number and did not receive one
```

You Should scrutinise your code and data for any instance where a function expects to receive a number but instead receives something else (like a character string or NA). NAs in your data could be a good place to start looking